# How to get triangle from complete graph not using DFS only adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithm, graph

[image]

[image] 
You can think as green = 1 and blue = 0, it is same as weighted adjacency matrix.

I solve finding uni-color triangle, it is a triangle with edges and each edge is same degree, so there is a weighted grpah from figure1 to figure2.

We can find with this triangle with DFS algorithm, but it takes O(n^2) - because it is complete graph. I want to make little time complexity.
Is there any possible to using matrix?

Comment: Mukltiplying your matrices doesn't sounds like an O(n) action. Sounds pretty much O(n^2) off the top of my head in fact so either I'm misunderstanding or you aren't taking it into account.

Comment: Sorry dude, it might take O(N^2)

Comment: Do you want to find any triangle or all triangles?

Answer (score 1):

Consider only the upper-left 6x6 submatrix, which is [guaranteed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) to contain a monochromatic triangle. O(1).

Comment: Surely the fact that you know there is one doesn't make it O(1) to find it? In fact, does it help at all?

Comment: @Chris Not only is there one, there is one in every 6-node induced subgraph.

Comment: Hmm... on thinking about it we may be thinking of different things. I was assuming he wanted to find all triangles. If he just wants to find one then you may be right.

Comment: @Chris It's possible. I assumed it was just one because the fastest algorithm to count (never mind list) as far as I know involves matrix multiplication and is little-omega(n^2).